# Does EF6 rc1 require .NET 4.5?

Tags: entity-framework

I couldn't find a definite answer to this question.

.NET 4.5 target framework is not an option for many of our customers at the moment, as .NET 4.5 in turn requires Server 2008 R2 SP1 or better.

Comment: The minimum for .NET 4.5 is actually 2008 (not R2) service pack 2 - if that makes a difference?

Comment: That actually makes a difference - thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity Framework 6 supports .NET 4.0: [Entity Framework 6 Specs](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=specs)